# Create a kubernetes cluster using Disks is not allowed in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want a kubernetes data to be backed up. So I have a persistent disk with kubernetes cluster and have set *reclaimPolicy: Retain* on storage.yaml file to make sure disks should not be deleted.

After the deletion of kubernetes cluster the disk retains on compute Engine -> Disks. But with the help of disk i am unable to create a kubernetes cluster. I have options only to create VM in GCP.

Is there a possible way to create a new kubernetes cluster with the existing disk on GCP

Answer (score 1):

To use your existing Persistent Disk in a new GKE cluster, you'll need to first create the new cluster, then:

- create and apply new PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim objects based on the name of your existing PD.
- Once those exist in your cluster, you'll be able to give a Pod's container access to that volume by specifying values for the container's `volumeMounts.mountPath` and `volumeMounts.name` in the pod definition file.

You'll find more details about how to achieve this in the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd).